# How to read div class name with number appended in Scrapy Python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

The webpage that i need to read has div class names that have a index number

```
 <div class="abber" id="abber1">
   <div class="Listing_All Listing_Level5_CONTAINER">
     <div class="Listing_Level5_HEADER">
        .....
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Listing_All Listing_Level4_CONTAINER">
     <div class="Listing_Level4_HEADER">
        .....
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Listing_All Listing_Level3_CONTAINER">
     <div class="Listing_Level3_HEADER">
        .....
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

How can i write a selector for this? As of now i have this

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"Listing_Level")]').extract()
```

But this would fetch everything that matches "Listing_Level". How can w add something like "Listing_Level*_Container" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you want, but you can try this:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"Listing_Level{}_Container")]'.format(n)).extract()
```

n is the number that you want for example if you want to select "Listing_Level5_Container" then use:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"Listing_Level{}_Container")]'.format(5)).extract()
```